# CakePHP - Primary key issue, How to override default 'id' field as Primary Key

Tags: cakephp-2.4

CakePHP uses 'id' as primary key.
How can I override this limitation.

I have data_base with primary key as doc_it, and I am using save() for updating the records.

I have check previous threads, but wasn't able to fix the issue.

Comment: What is your model name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mention below code in your Model

```
public $primaryKey = 'doc_it';
```

and then you can use `$this->YourModel->id;` in your controller to access the primary key.

Comment: @BilalWani Won't you accept the answer if it is working?